# Junit classpath in ant: problems with dirset

Tags: ant, junit, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I'm getting troubles trying to use

```
<dirsets>
```

in my junit ant.
This is the snippet of the classpath.

```
<target name="myTests" >     
    <junit haltonerror="true" haltonfailure="true" fork="true">
        <classpath>
            <dirset dir="/my/absolute/root/path/where/I/keep/compiled/classes">
                <include name="com/mycompany/mytests"/>
                </dirset>
                <pathelement location="my/path/to/jars/myjar1.jar" />  
                <pathelement location="my/path/to/jars/myjar2.jar" />  
                <!-- and so on -->  
             </classpath>
    <test name="com.mycompany.mytests.MyFirstTest" 
               outfile="${dir.report.test}/report_MyFirstTest">
                <formatter type="xml" />
</test> 
    </junit>
   </target>
```

when I launch the test, after having successfully compiled all the code, ant complains:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.mytests.MyFirstTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
```

I tried with absolute, relative paths and it never works. My classpath consists on many jars specified with many   and that  that is never recognized.
Where is my fault?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I former times when I used ant I used the nested [`<classpath>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html#nested) element and specified the classpath with the [path-like](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) structure - like this:

```
<path id="project.test.classpath">
    <pathelement location="/my/absolute/root/path/where/I/keep/compiled/classes" />
    <fileset dir="/my/path/to/jars">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>


<target name="myTests">
    <junit haltonerror="true" haltonfailure="true" fork="true">
        <classpath refid="project.test.classpath" />
        <test name="com.mycompany.mytests.MyFirstTest" outfile="${dir.report.test}/report_MyFirstTest">
            <formatter type="xml" />
        </test>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Maybe that fit's also for you.